# Get ID from modal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a block of code running 3 times that will display some books and have a button to add a review.
Review button fires a modal popup with form to fill to create a review.
I am feeling dumb but I cant find a way to get a ID of a bookto use to create a review.
Was thinkink to display it within add reiew button params but dont know how to pass it after form submit (with other button pressed withtin form itself)

Comment: I guess I should have added - all have to be done with ROR only - adding scripts out of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template view for each book

```
<div class="book-#{book.id}">
  ... other stuff
  <button class="review-create"> Write Review </button>
</div>
```

Javascript to display modal

```
$('.review-create').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // might not be parent() here but you can call parent() as many times as you want
  var bookId = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('class').split('-')[1];   

  // other stuff for ajax or pass bookId into modal method
  // Modal.displayForBook(bookId);
});
```

Now that your modal has the `bookId`, you can submit it through `ajax` by just referencing the variable. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Because you can't edit the current script, you can write a new script in the view.

_book.html.erb

```
<script type='javascript/text'>
  $('modal-button').click(function(e) {
    $('review-create').attr('id', "#{book.id}");
  });
</script
```

modal.html.erb

Your modal will submit ajax, dont make it do the `form_for` helpers

```
<script type='javascript/text'>
   $('form.create').on('submit', function(e) {
     var bookId = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('id');

     // ajax call here
     // on success, $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr('id', null)
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Should have mentioned I need to use ruby for this - cant add JS

Comment: How are you displaying the modal without javascript? Do you have one modal per book item? Do you have one button per book or just one button at the top of the page to add a review?

Comment: modal is displayed with JS - its just that I cant edit it. Its displayed with button with data-toggle="modal" 
Also there is singlle model form pper page (not per book)that isi hidden and revealed via button.

Comment: Why cant you write a new `script` within the `_book.html.erb`? The `script` can assign an `ID` to the modal and remove the `ID` on submit/close of the modal.  If that really isn't a possiblity, then I would recommend just making a dropdown of the books and have the user select which book to write the review for.

Comment: aw and its a button per book but same hidden modal

Comment: Edited my answer based on your comment. If you can't modify the modal script, you can just write a new script within the view. Not recommended to have your javascript everywhere but you have very few choices if you cant modify other's existing code. OR you can just use a dropdown select/option (lol).

Comment: I would rather use a data attribute in my HTML element than concatenating the id in the ID of the element, for example: `<div class... data-book-id="<%= book.id %>">`